# Is there a call-forwarding iOS app that works by schedule?

Tags: ios, iphone-app

I work in an IT team where we rotate an iPhone each week and take off-hours calls. The standard business hours start at 8AM, when our help desk begins routing incoming issues to us via e-mail instead of via phone calls.

My team, however, has several members who get to work at 7AM. They will respond to issues from 7AM to 8AM, so that the on-call person doesn't have to. The problem is that our help desk has a high turnover, so training them on when to call the on-call phone vs sending an email during this special case has not proven effective.

What we'd like is a call-forwarding app on our iPhone that will automatically forward the calls to one of these 7AM employees' work phones, **only between 7AM and 8AM**. Is there such an app available on the app store currently?

Paid or unpaid apps are both fine options.